# Input and checking if true , Function returns old value

Tags: python-3.x, function

I've function asking question and comparing it, if is not matching 'yes' it does call itself to ask question again.
The problem is that when function is called second time it returns old value.

```
def question():
    ask = input("Are you OK?:").lower()
    if ask != 'yes':
        question()
    return ask

print (question())

#output:
Are you OK?:no
Are you OK?:no
Are you OK?:yes
no

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've tried different way by adding elif then it was returning none so I came to another idea with nested function and parameters no expected results as well.

```
def question():
    ask = input("Are you OK?:").lower()

    def check_question(n):
        if ask != 'yes':
            question()
        else:
            return ask

    m = check_question(ask)
    print (m)
question()

#output:
Are you OK?:no
Are you OK?:yes
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You are not storing what the recursive call is returning.  All you are doing on a "no" answer is calling the function again and ignoring the result.  So it eventually it just returns the original (top level) contents of ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a very good candidate for recursion, as I said in my comment.
You just want a simple while loop:

```
ask='no'
while ask != 'yes':
    ask = input("Are you OK? ").lower()
```

Comment: Yep, thanks that do the job.
Easy, I'm surprised I didn't come to that :)

Thanks